# How would I find the imaginary roots given a quadratic?

Tags: php, math, refactoring

This code finds the two roots of a quadratic equation in the form ax^2+bx+c

Is my solution good time/space-complexity wise, and how I would go about allowing users to see the imaginary roots if the quadratic has any?

```
public function factor($a=0, $b=0, $c=0) {

       $positive_solution = (-$b + sqrt($b**2-4*$a*$c))/2*$a;
       $negative_solution = (-$b - sqrt($b**2-4*$a*$c))/2*$a;

        if($b**2-4*$a*$c < 0) {
            return "Solutions are imaginary";
        }

       $factor_one = $positive_solution * -1;
       $factor_two = $negative_solution * -1;

       $factor_one > 0 ? $factor_one = "+ " . $factor_one : $factor_one = "- " . $factor_one;
       $factor_two > 0 ? $factor_two = "+ " . $factor_two : $factor_two = "- " . $factor_two;

        return "Your roots are located at (0, " . $positive_solution . ")(0, " . $negative_solution . "), 
        Thus, the problem can be factored into (x " . $factor_one . ")(x " . $factor_two . ")";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. the `if($b**2-4*$a*$c < 0)` is too late

   You already used the `sqrt` so domain error might be thrown move the if to start
2. for imaginary part you just use negation or abs value

   simply `sqrt(-($b**2-4*$a*$c))` or `sqrt(abs($b**2-4*$a*$c))` not sure if php uses abs or fabs for floats or if you even use floats... (havent code in php for ages)

I would combine this to something like this (just pseudo code as the var $ makes me dizzy :) ):

```
q = b*b-4*a*c
d = sqrt(abs(q))

if (q<0) 
  {
  a0 = -b/(2*a);
  b0 = +d/(2*a);
  a1 = -b/(2*a);
  b1 = -d/(2*a);
  }
else
  {
  a0 = (-b + d)/(2*a);
  b0 = 0
  a1 = (-b - d)/(2*a);
  b1 = 0
  }
```

Where `a0+i*b0` and `a1+i*b1` are the 2 solutions where `i=sqrt(-1)`